# How do I archive/compress files using the right click menu in Nautilus-elementary?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, nautilus-elementary, compression, archive

In Lucid, after selecting a bunch of files, when you right-clicked on the selection in the file manager, you could select compress and a nice simple window came up for doing just that.

In Oneiric, I cannot find that option. So somebody please tell me what I might be missing? Some of the things in Unity are really irritating.

I did have nautilus from the nautilus-elementary ppa installed instead of the normal version.

Comment: In default Nautilus right click compressen works as expected.

Comment: Remove nautilus elementary. The default nautilus in 11.10 supports compression perfectly.

Comment: I don't have nautilus elementary in Oneiric. I was just mentioning my case of Lucid. I see my mistake! On a file that looks like some sort of archive already, the compress option disappears.

Comment: @Eshwar Please do not put the answer in the question. Instead please use the answer box to indicate this is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It just doesn't show up if you select a file that's somehow an archive already i.e. self-extracting exe, some normal exe files, etc.